# Obtener el número mayor en python

Tags: python, python-2.7

No se como hacerlo me pueden ayudar

Encontrar el mayor valor de un conjunto de `n` números ingresados desde el teclado

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n_mayor = 0
k = 1
c = input("Escriba la cantidad de numeros que desea comparar: ")
while k<=c:
    n = float(input("Digitar numero: "))
    if n>n_mayor:
        n_mayor = n
    else:
        n_mayor = n_mayor
    k = k+1
print "El mayor numero es: ",n_mayor
raw_input()
```

Funciona en python 2.7